# Not able to signup using firebase auth module

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Our requirement**

Signup using email/password with Firebase SDK on android

**Problem**

The onComplete() method is not getting called. No error / exception is thrown. 
note: We have enabled the email/password provider on Firebase console

Please find the code below -

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            if (v == saveView) {
                String email = emailView.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordView.getText().toString();
                if (validate(email, password)) {

                    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(UserRegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("BIG", e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }

 private boolean validate(String email , String password){
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Is the issue resolved? I'm facing the same one

Comment: facing same issue with some of my users, some of them get successful some don't....do you have any solution for this so far

Answer (score 0):

**Try This It's Work for me maybe it's help you**

```
 firebase.createUser(etEmail.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString(), new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {


                    System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));

                }
                @Override
                public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    // there was an error

                    String errorMessage = firebaseError.getMessage();

                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, ""+errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            });
```

**For Login**

```
 firebase.authWithPassword(etEmail.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString(), new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "User Authenticated");

                    System.out.println("User ID: " + authData.getUid() + ", Provider: " + authData.getProvider());

                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    switch (firebaseError.getCode()) {
                        case FirebaseError.USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST:
                            // handle a non existing user

                            Log.e(TAG, "User Does Not Exist");
                            break;
                        case FirebaseError.INVALID_PASSWORD:
                            // handle an invalid password
                            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid Password");
                            break;
                        default:
                            // handle other errors
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Check out the Google Firebase documentation the code is different https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account

Comment: @AshutoshKumar also read this https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

Comment: @AshutoshKumar maybe this method is deprecated but still it working fine

Answer (score 0):

For **Firebase old API** Try this

```
fbRoot.authWithPassword("email", "pasw", new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User ID: " + authData.getUid() + ", Provider: " + authData.getProvider(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

And this for **Creating** Account

```
fbRoot.createUser("email", "password", new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: REMEMBER, Your email should follow EMAIL FORMAT ( blaablaaa@blaa.blaa ),

Comment: check the Google Firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account

Comment: mhhh, you are talking about new API, thankss, let me check it. thanks